# NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found || Not able to play asset audio in WebApp

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test, audio-player

I'm not able to run my added audio when I'm running this code in my WebApp. It's showing this error, pls help if someone can rectify it.

Click the link, In this image you can see the error it's showing, pls help

[image: 1]

p.s. - I'm doing angela yu flutter course

Comment: Your error is saying that you can't play a `.wave` on the web.

Comment: Thank you Denzel for the reply, do you know what file should I choose then ?

Comment: .mp3 or .mp4 should work just fine

Comment: No same error is coming, I think, it;s about web support or something like that